# Adding conditions to all finds in a model in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: database-design, activerecord, model, rails-activerecord

Tried to search for everything on google however could not find anything similar to CakePHP's beforeFind() callback in Ruby on rails.

So I have a News Model currently.

```
    class News < NewsRecord
    end
```

The news model's find method has already been used in many places around the site in controllers everywhere. I have now added a publish_web(boolean) column to the news model.

What I want in this News model is to add a condition that gets added to all find conditions happening on this model. So something like this:

```
    class News < NewsRecord
        :conditions => {:published_web => true}
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use scopes, one way to do it is

```
class News < NewsRecord
  scope :published, where(published_web: true)
end
```

Which will allow you to do `News.published` and will return all record that fits the condition in the scope.

Other way is to set a `default_scope`, which will "replace" all fetch in the `News` table by the condition in the `default_scope` (please keep in mind that this can be "dangerous").

```
class News < NewsRecord
  default_scope where(published_web: true)
end
```

Comment: YES thats it THANKS! default_scope where(:publish_web => true)    #alternative syntax

Comment: Yep this is a valid syntax too, edited my answer to make it cleaner.

Comment: If it helped and you could upvote/accept the answer I'd be very grateful =)